# Email Not Send to Multiple User Cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I want to send email to all user in database `users`. I use cakePHP, when i try the error is :

> the email just send to first user in array

this is EmailTemplatesController.php

```
 public function admin_send_notification() {

    $this->loadModel("EmailTemplate");
    $this->loadModel("User");

    $adminEmailData = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 313)));
    $userData = $this->User->find('all', array('fields'=>array('email'), 'conditions' => array('User.role_id' => 2)));

    $check = [];    
    foreach ($userData as $value) {
        array_push($check, $value['User']);
    }

    $email = [];
    foreach ($check as $value) {
        array_push($email, $value['email']);
    }


    $adminEmailFrom = $adminEmailData['User']['email']; 

    $this->app_update_notification($email,'app-update-notification',$adminEmailFrom);

}

function app_update_notification($email, $slug, $adminEmailFrom) {  

    $this->loadModel('EmailTemplate');
    foreach ($email as $to) {

    $from           =   $adminEmailFrom;

    $mail_message   =   ''; 

    $emailTemplate  =   $this->EmailTemplate->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('EmailTemplate.slug'=>$slug)));

    $subject    =   $emailTemplate['EmailTemplate']['subject'];

    $mailMessage = str_replace(array('{NAME}','{SITE}'), array(Configure::read('Site.title')), $emailTemplate['EmailTemplate']['description']);
    $Template = 'default';        
    parent::__sendMail($to, $subject, $mailMessage, $from ,$Template);
    $this->Session->setFlash("Email has been send",'admin_flash_good');
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'email_templates', 'action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

this is was AppController.php

```
public function __sendMail($To, $Subject, $message, $From, $template = 'default', $smtp = 1, $attachment = array() ) {

    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    // echo $smtp;die;
    $email  =   new CakeEmail();
    $email->config();
    $email->to($To);
    $email->from($From); 
    $email->subject($Subject);
    $email->emailFormat('html');
    $email->attachments($attachment) ;
    $email->template($template);

    $email->layout  =   'default';

    if ($email->send($message)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

whats should i do? please help

Comment: You're issuing a redirect inside of your `foreach` loop.

Comment: so what should i do? should i use while? please help

Comment: i have edited the question @ndm

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was kinda obvious... do not redirect inside of the loop, do it after the loop (same goes for defining the flash message). No matter the type of loop, issuing a redirect will cause the loop, respectively the whole application execution to be halted.

Comment: i have changed redirect became after foreach. but the error is : the email will be send to last user in array.